# How do I get external image and encode it to base64 on client WebApp?

Tags: javascript, cors

Here is current code:

```
toBase64(url, callback, outputFormat){
  var img = new Image();
  img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
  img.onload = function(){
    var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var dataURL;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    canvas.width = this.width;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
    callback(dataURL);
    canvas = null; 
  };
  img.src = url;
}
```

I can't find the way over CORS error to retrieve external image.
Also, I use [x-ray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray) in my NodeJS server, and it is able to retrieve the same images. I assume, this means that it is possible to go over CORS error on client side too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately CORS restrictions apply specifically to webpages. Your server does not experience CORS errors because it lives in a world where you have some control over the machine and are a trusted user. Webpages in browsers are a different story. They are completely under the authority of the browser to approve and facilitate any network usage.

That said, there are a number of famous ways to get around CORS, such as by exploiting the more liberal restrictions on requests made by script tags. However almost all of them involve only GET requests so you might be out of luck.

My advice would be to use your server as a kind of proxy. Make special endpoints where you route requests and responses through your own server and you will have fundamentally escaped CORS. It puts more strain on your server but I have done this before and it worked quite well.